# auto start app after call end it is not working in Redmi but it working in Moto ,Nokia

Tags: android

Not working in redmi because in Developer option -> Turn on MIUI optimuization in enable but when i disable it that time my app is Automatic on

Comment: How i overcome this problem please help..

Comment: Please show me what you tried till now ?

Comment: i just add reboot permision

Comment: android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: This might not work in all the mobile devices like Honor and others

Comment: but true caller is working .. how?

Comment: I don't know but you could ask to treucaller for more details sorry

Comment: how should i ask .. do u know?